socket.io/OkHttp leaks threads after closing the program
I'm using io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0 in my libGDX Java App and I run it on desktop with Android Studio.
The problem is that when I close the app's window, the app is still active.
I noticed that this happens only if I use socket.io, even if I properly close the socket as the official Faq says and by freeing also other stuff.
In the build.gradle:core I already tried to use a newer version of okhttp:
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
eclipse.project.name = appName + '-core'

dependencies {
  api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
  api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
  api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
  api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
  api ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0')
  api ('io.socket:engine.io-client:2.1.0') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
  }
  api ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
  }
}

GameScreen.java:
MyGame game;

private Socket socketIo;
private Dispatcher dispatcher;
private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

public class GameScreen extends InputAdapter implements Screen
{
    public GameScreen(final MyGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        URI uri = URI.create("wss://mydomain.app:8080");
        dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .dispatcher(dispatcher)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // important for HTTP long-polling
            .build();
        IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
        options.callFactory = okHttpClient;
        options.webSocketFactory = okHttpClient;
        options.auth = singletonMap("serverOffset", "0");
        options.timeout = 10000;
        options.reconnectionAttempts = 3;
        socketIo = IO.socket(uri, options);
        socketIo.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        if(socketIo != null) {
            socketIo.disconnect();

            socketIo.off();
            socketIo.offAnyIncoming();
            socketIo.offAnyOutgoing();
            if(okHttpClient != null) {
                okHttpClient.connectionPool().evictAll();
                okHttpClient.dispatcher().cancelAll();
                okHttpClient.dispatcher().executorService().shutdownNow();
                okHttpClient.connectionSpecs().clear();
            }

            socketIo = null;
        }
    }
}

If I run jstack [appProceddId], it outputs this:
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-120.04 mixed mode, sharing):

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00007fb898001920, length=24, elements={
...
}

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=1,12ms elapsed=16,96s tid=0x00007fb92815c090 nid=0x4c24 waiting on condition  [0x00007fb92c78f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@17.0.9/Reference.java:253)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@17.0.9/Reference.java:215)

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=0,47ms elapsed=16,96s tid=0x00007fb92815d480 nid=0x4c25 in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb92c68e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000732849a78> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@17.0.9/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    - locked <0x0000000732849a78> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@17.0.9/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Finalizer.java:172)

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0,64ms elapsed=16,95s tid=0x00007fb928162a30 nid=0x4c26 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Service Thread" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=1,48ms elapsed=16,95s tid=0x00007fb928163df0 nid=0x4c27 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Monitor Deflation Thread" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=2,21ms elapsed=16,95s tid=0x00007fb928165210 nid=0x4c28 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=1656,00ms elapsed=16,95s tid=0x00007fb928166bd0 nid=0x4c29 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"C1 CompilerThread0" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=1430,74ms elapsed=16,95s tid=0x00007fb928168110 nid=0x4c2a waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"Sweeper thread" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0,12ms elapsed=16,95s tid=0x00007fb928171580 nid=0x4c2b runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Notification Thread" #12 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0,17ms elapsed=16,92s tid=0x00007fb928179490 nid=0x4c2c runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Common-Cleaner" #13 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=1,02ms elapsed=16,91s tid=0x00007fb92817ccb0 nid=0x4c2e in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb90814e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000732824e20> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@17.0.9/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    - locked <0x0000000732824e20> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@17.0.9/CleanerImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Thread.java:840)
    at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/InnocuousThread.java:162)

"Timer-0" #18 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,69ms elapsed=10,04s tid=0x00007fb929767790 nid=0x4c4f in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb8619d8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007350d7500> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Object.java:338)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:537)
    - locked <0x00000007350d7500> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:516)

"Timer-2" #21 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,42ms elapsed=9,62s tid=0x00007fb929762b60 nid=0x4c52 in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb8aef61000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000734e32a68> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Object.java:338)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:537)
    - locked <0x0000000734e32a68> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:516)

"OkHttp TaskRunner" #23 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=6,87ms elapsed=9,36s tid=0x00007fb7dc08de30 nid=0x4c56 waiting on condition  [0x00007fb861ad9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000732896b80> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@17.0.9/LockSupport.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(java.base@17.0.9/SynchronousQueue.java:401)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(java.base@17.0.9/SynchronousQueue.java:903)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Thread.java:840)

"Okio Watchdog" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1,72ms elapsed=9,35s tid=0x00007fb7dc091a80 nid=0x4c57 waiting on condition  [0x00007fb860fd4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000734d8f6e0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@17.0.9/LockSupport.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@17.0.9/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1757)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$Companion.awaitTimeout$okio(AsyncTimeout.kt:308)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog.run(AsyncTimeout.kt:186)

"Timer-3" #25 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,35ms elapsed=9,30s tid=0x00007fb92976ba90 nid=0x4c58 in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb860ed3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000734e37060> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Object.java:338)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:537)
    - locked <0x0000000734e37060> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:516)

"Timer-4" #32 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,39ms elapsed=8,99s tid=0x00007fb9297d5690 nid=0x4c5f in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb861cdb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000734e393f8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Object.java:338)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:537)
    - locked <0x0000000734e393f8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:516)

"Timer-5" #36 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,37ms elapsed=8,67s tid=0x00007fb9297f0070 nid=0x4c64 in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb860acf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000734e3b6e8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Object.java:338)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:537)
    - locked <0x0000000734e3b6e8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:516)

"Timer-6" #38 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,34ms elapsed=8,35s tid=0x00007fb9297ca960 nid=0x4c67 in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb860bd0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000734e3d9d8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Object.java:338)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:537)
    - locked <0x0000000734e3d9d8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:516)

"OkHttp TaskRunner" #42 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5,06ms elapsed=8,22s tid=0x00007fb7f003fc50 nid=0x4c6b waiting on condition  [0x00007fb8608cd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000732896b80> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@17.0.9/LockSupport.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(java.base@17.0.9/SynchronousQueue.java:401)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(java.base@17.0.9/SynchronousQueue.java:903)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Thread.java:840)

"Timer-7" #43 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,37ms elapsed=8,04s tid=0x00007fb9297ee330 nid=0x4c6c in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb8609ce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000734e3fc70> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Object.java:338)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:537)
    - locked <0x0000000734e3fc70> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:516)

"OkHttp TaskRunner" #46 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,22ms elapsed=8,03s tid=0x00007fb7c0001b10 nid=0x4c6f waiting on condition  [0x00007fb8606cb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000732896b80> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@17.0.9/LockSupport.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(java.base@17.0.9/SynchronousQueue.java:401)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(java.base@17.0.9/SynchronousQueue.java:903)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@17.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Thread.java:840)

"Timer-8" #47 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0,45ms elapsed=7,72s tid=0x00007fb9297cbb20 nid=0x4c70 in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb8607cc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000734e41ec8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.9/Object.java:338)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:537)
    - locked <0x0000000734e41ec8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(java.base@17.0.9/Timer.java:516)

"DestroyJavaVM" #56 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=3331,05ms elapsed=5,86s tid=0x00007fb9280173f0 nid=0x4c18 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #57 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0,45ms elapsed=0,10s tid=0x00007fb898000d20 nid=0x4c8c waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=9,78ms elapsed=16,97s tid=0x00007fb928158100 nid=0x4c23 runnable  

"GC Thread#0" os_prio=0 cpu=9,65ms elapsed=17,01s tid=0x00007fb9280780f0 nid=0x4c19 runnable  

"GC Thread#1" os_prio=0 cpu=9,57ms elapsed=15,44s tid=0x00007fb8a8005d50 nid=0x4c45 runnable  

"GC Thread#2" os_prio=0 cpu=9,41ms elapsed=15,44s tid=0x00007fb8a8006800 nid=0x4c46 runnable  

"GC Thread#3" os_prio=0 cpu=3,53ms elapsed=15,44s tid=0x00007fb8a80072b0 nid=0x4c47 runnable  

"GC Thread#4" os_prio=0 cpu=9,38ms elapsed=15,44s tid=0x00007fb8a8007d60 nid=0x4c48 runnable  

"GC Thread#5" os_prio=0 cpu=6,61ms elapsed=15,44s tid=0x00007fb8a800d3d0 nid=0x4c49 runnable  

"GC Thread#6" os_prio=0 cpu=0,33ms elapsed=10,07s tid=0x00007fb8a800bbc0 nid=0x4c4c runnable  

"GC Thread#7" os_prio=0 cpu=0,25ms elapsed=10,07s tid=0x00007fb8a800c5c0 nid=0x4c4d runnable  

"G1 Main Marker" os_prio=0 cpu=0,10ms elapsed=17,01s tid=0x00007fb928086f80 nid=0x4c1a runnable  

"G1 Conc#0" os_prio=0 cpu=0,07ms elapsed=17,01s tid=0x00007fb928087ef0 nid=0x4c1b runnable  

"G1 Refine#0" os_prio=0 cpu=0,15ms elapsed=17,01s tid=0x00007fb92812a130 nid=0x4c1c runnable  

"G1 Service" os_prio=0 cpu=4,72ms elapsed=17,01s tid=0x00007fb92812b030 nid=0x4c1d runnable  

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=14,46ms elapsed=16,92s tid=0x00007fb92817ade0 nid=0x4c2d waiting on condition  

JNI global refs: 18, weak refs: 0

As you can see, there are these socket.io related threads still active:

OkHttp TaskRunner
Okio Watchdog


I cannot simple do System.exit(0) (that works well) because I'll publish the app on PlayStore and this code is not recommended for an Android App. I just tested that running on Android the App is still running after it being closed, so the only actual way I found to prevent socket.io/OkHTTP leaks is to do System.exit(0)...
So, how to definetely shutdown socket.io and all related threads?

Sorry for my ignorance but I do not know how to run this code in an Android project, can you put a reproducer somewhere please ?

@ozkanpakdil np, you should download the LibGDX project creation tool (https://libgdx.com/wiki/start/project-generation) and then try the code I posted above. Thanks

You're already attempting to shut it down in the dispose() method, but it seems like the threads associated with OkHttp are still active. What you can do is before exiting your application, wait for the socket.io and OkHttp threads to terminate. There might be some additional cleanup needed, try to modify your dispose() method to wait for threads to terminate:
@Override
public void dispose() {
    if (socketIo != null) {
        socketIo.disconnect();

        // Wait for socket.io threads to terminate
        try {
            socketIo.getExecutor().shutdown(); // shutdown the internal executor
            socketIo.getExecutor().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for termination
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // unregister listeners and handlers
        socketIo.off();
        socketIo.offAnyIncoming();
        socketIo.offAnyOutgoing();

        // properly shutdown OkHttp client
        if (okHttpClient != null) {
            okHttpClient.dispatcher().cancelAll();
            okHttpClient.connectionPool().evictAll();
            okHttpClient.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown(); // shutdown dispatcher's executor
            try {
                okHttpClient.dispatcher().executorService().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for termination
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        socketIo = null;
    }
}

Since you are waiting for the threads to terminate before allowing the application to exit, it ensures that all resources are properly released, which should prevent memory leaks and unexpected behavior.

But if I wait the threads termination, what the impact on Android devices? I need to immediately close them and then close the app, otherwise there is a UX issue e.g. the user may notice the app isn't closing immediately and Google also can consider the App to have some leaks because it needs more time (e.g. 5 seconds) to close.

It would cause a bit delay and could impact UX since users expect apps to close quickly. In that case, Instead of waiting for the threads to terminate synchronously in the dispose() method, you can initiate the cleanup process asynchronously or  the cleanup tasks with background threads, allowing the main UI thread to continue closing the app without waiting for the cleanup to finish. Later approach allows your app to close quickly while ensuring that cleanup tasks are performed in the background, i would recommend that.

I understand but what if the thread does not close in 5 seconds? In this case I have the same initial problem. I need to be sure that all threads are closed.

In that case, as a failsafe you can forcefully shuts down the threads if they do not terminate gracefully within 5 seconds.
